# Change pipe symbol to space using sed

Tags: sed, pipe, space

I'm generating a word list by parsing Wikipedia using sed on cygwin.
Want to change the pipe symbol `|` to a space.
`sed 's/\|/ /g'` fails.
It puts a blank space between every pair of characters.

Comment: `\|` is reserved for OR statement in sed commands.

Answer (score 2):

Don't escape `|` or use sed's option `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `tr`, whose sole purpose is to *tr*anslate characters:

```
tr '|' ' ' < filename
```

It's even shorter to type. If you don't mind losing readability, you could shorten it to

```
tr \| \ <filename
```

Answer (score -1):

This works. I can use the hex representation:

```
sed 's/\x7c//g'
```

Comment: or. even better you can just do what's stated in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37360214/1745001). Also, it's not relevant in this case but never use hex representations, use octal instead - google it if you don't know why.